# Synchronous/asynchronous behavior

Tags: angular

I am still new to Angular and trying to learn.

I have a component header which has a child component button which has a button Add. I want to change the color/text of that button whenever I click it.
I want all components to be aware of the state of this button so I m using a service: ui and adding a : showddTask property that will define the state of the button (true or false) and passing this property in a subject like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UiService {


   showddTask: boolean = false;
  subject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }
  toggleAddTask(): void {
    this.showddTask = !this.showddTask;
    this.subject.next(this.showddTask);
  }


}
```

Then the header component:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UiService } from 'src/app/services/ui.service';
import { Subscription,Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  title = 'angular-crash';
  textInput = "ghfhf";
  addTaskButtonState: boolean = false;
  
  
  constructor(private uiService: UiService){
  }

public toggleAddTask(): void {
  
  this.uiService.toggleAddTask();
  this.uiService.subject.subscribe((value)=>this.addTaskButtonState=value)
  
  

}
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.textInput)
  console.log(this.addTaskButtonState)
}

}
```

and in my header component.html:

```
<header>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <app-button color="{{addTaskButtonState? 'red':'Green'}}" 
     text="{{addTaskButtonState? 'Close':'Add'}}" (btnClick)="toggleAddTask()"></app-button>
</header>
```

For some reason, I need to click the Add button 3 times before I start seeing the change.
But when I put the subscribe part in the constructor it works right away.
Can someone please explain how and why this behavior happens and if it has to do with the synchronous/asynchronous behavior?

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UiService } from 'src/app/services/ui.service';
import { Subscription,Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  title = 'angular-crash';
  textInput = "ghfhf";
  addTaskButtonState: boolean = false;
  
  
  constructor(private uiService: UiService){
    this.uiService.subject.subscribe((value)=>this.addTaskButtonState=value)
    this.uiService.toggleAddTask();
  }

public toggleAddTask(): void {
  
  this.uiService.toggleAddTask();
  
  
  

}
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.textInput)
  console.log(this.addTaskButtonState)
}

  
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to click the Add button three times before seeing the change is related to the subscription timing and the order of execution.

In your original code, when you click the Add button, the toggleAddTask() method is called, which in turn calls this.uiService.toggleAddTask() to update the showddTask property and emit the new value through the subject. Then, in the same method, you subscribe to the subject to receive the new value and update the addTaskButtonState property accordingly.

The issue is that the subscription is set up after the first click, so the initial click doesn't have an immediate effect. However, subsequent clicks trigger the subscription, and the button state is updated correctly.

In the second code snippet you provided, you moved the subscription to the constructor. This means that the subscription is set up immediately when the HeaderComponent is created. Additionally, you call this.uiService.toggleAddTask() in the constructor, which triggers the subscription and updates the button state right away.

By moving the subscription to the constructor and calling toggleAddTask() in the constructor, you ensure that the button state is updated before the component is even displayed, eliminating the need for additional clicks.

To summarize, the behavior you observed is due to the timing of the subscription setup. When the subscription is set up after the click, you need additional clicks to trigger the subscription and update the button state. When the subscription is set up in the constructor, the button state is updated immediately, without the need for additional clicks.